# Variable added to a link is empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm fetching a value from database and adding it in `<a>` tag, using PHP. When, I click such link, I can clerly see, that there is only a static part in its `href` attribute and there is no variable added.

For example, I want `www.domain.com/client?client=SLCH12345678` URL, where `SLCH12345678` is taken from database (a variable value), but all, I am getting, is `www.domain.com/client?client=`.

This is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT customer_ref, f_name, l_name FROM client_details WHERE ".$searchtype." LIKE '%".$searchterm."%'";
$result = $db->query($query);

$customer_ref = $query['customer_ref'];
$num_results = $result->num_rows;

echo "<p>Number of clients found: ".$num_results."</p>";

for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Name: ";
    echo "<a href='client.php?client=$customer_ref'>";
    echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['f_name']));
    echo "&nbsp;";
    echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['l_name']));
    echo "</a></strong>";
    echo "<br/>Address: ";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `stripslashes` <- wth? (The database already contains garbage if this is at all relevant.)

Comment: so if $query is a string how can you access elements in it like its an associative array?

Comment: yer $query['customer_ref']; is empty but there is a customer ref in the database and sorry what is a query result parsing function i new to php and still learning all that sort of thing

Comment: And does that customer_ref in the database match the search criteria you're applying?

Comment: this bit of the coding started of as a search function and i edited to be able to click on and send me to another page to be able to see all my clients detail so i can edit them and talk to my client about there problems more quickly

Comment: $query['customer_ref'] doesn't exist....I think you meant to do $result['customer_ref'] which still seems like it would be wrong.  $query isnt an array, its a string...

Comment: i tried do it will $result but then it goes to the page it should do but shows the text i have put in for if someone click on the search button and no put anything in the text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not fetching anything, you're just querying. You've tagged `mysqli`, so let's do it with `mysqli`.

```
$result = $db->query($query);
$query = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

You would then loop through each result set.

```
$query = "SELECT customer_ref, f_name, l_name FROM client_details WHERE ".$searchtype." LIKE '%".$searchterm."%'";
$result = $db->query($query);

echo "<p>Number of clients found: ". $result->num_rows ."</p>";
$i = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<p><strong>".($i).". Name: ";
  echo "<a href='client.php?client=". $row['customer_ref'] ."'>";
  echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['f_name']));
  echo "&nbsp;";
  echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['l_name']));
  echo "</a></strong>";
  echo "<br/>Address: ";
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: so what i would just put in $query = $result->fetch_assoc(); and thew rest should fall in to place with this code

Comment: Yeah, assuming `$db` holds a `mysqli` object.

Comment: i think it does i think i may have jumping between mysql and mysqli

Comment: it works but it now messing with the list of client it show client one but client 2 it does not it looks like this Number of clients found: 2

1. Name: jess snelling
Address:

2. Name:  
Address:

Comment: thank you you get the approved answer thank you again sorry if this question sounded stupid bet you lot get sick and tired of newbees lol

Comment: Glad it's all worked out for you @aaronhead :) (& thanks for the approval)